# iOS app - authenticating a user for an asp.net web app

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone, authentication, nsurlsession

I'd really appreciate a quick opinion on whether I am approaching the following in the correct way.

A friend has asked me if I could help him put together an app for his startup company.
They have a server running some flavour of an asp.net application.

He wants an iOS app that will allow a user to login and manage their account.

I'm checking out NSURLSession and NSURLSessionDataTask.

Here is what I have to get it going:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myfriendssite.com/Account/Login"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObject delegate:self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"reponse: %@",response);
    if(error == nil)
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        NSLog(@"code: %d", httpResp.statusCode);

        NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [webView loadHTMLString:text baseURL:url];
        NSLog(@"Data: %@",text);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

When I shoot off the task using [task resume] I receive the "didReceiveChallenge" for the task.
At that point I respond with:

```
NSURLCredentialPersistence persistence = NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone;
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[usernameField text] password:[passworField text] persistence:persistence];
completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
```

But do I need to do something in regards to the cookie that comes back with the response?

```
"Set-Cookie" = "__RequestVerificationToken=cIxrC6dJnHyD6pIe-zgkx_Hr0CbsRZ7_dbQfsSIWsFAtVXjV_-o4d_2GycwhY0E-JjyA8R3iNsTreVOIcTNWQvxBenlEMLe8RJ5vz6JcyRSjLNn7H1Uklu0MD-afm08RVe7L8m4DzvtJv5rTAAie-w2; path=/; HttpOnly";
```

I'm pretty out of my element here so I'd appreciate any pointers!

Cheers!

Adam

Comment: as i bumble my way through this I see now that inside the NSURLSession I now have the cookie once the task has run - NSLog(@"%@",defaultSession.configuration.HTTPCookieStorage.cookies); It does show "isSecure:FALSE" - that sounds like something i'll need to look into. I can't tell if I have logged in yet though